# Smooth jquery/javascript animations

Tags: jquery, animation, smoothing

I am using jquery for sliding content up and down but it's not delivering the smoothness i need.
The animations work fine on webkit browsers like chrome and safari but give awful performance on mozilla based browsers.

How can i make my jquery animations to be as smooth as these - http://www.audentio.com/preview/mybb/darkseries

What is the secret for that smooth animation?

Comment: Are you using the same version of jQuery as the site you want to emulate (1.7.0)? Are you perchance tinkering with the value of `$.fx.interval`?

Comment: not a solution, but you could try other libraries if you're just animating, for example http://www.greensock.com , take a look at this: http://www.greensock.com/js/speed.html

Comment: The tweenlite library looks promising. I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

There is no single thing that guarantees smooth animation.  Animation speed depends on how much of what work needs to be done by the layout engine.  When your animation is slow, what is it that's slow?  Firebug has a pretty good profiler, so you should be able to figure out where the time's being taken and take steps to mitigate.

Also, constructing a minimal sample that you can share with Stack Overflow will help with getting accurate answers.  Show us the code!  :)

Comment: The slide works fine on a minimal page (with just the elements)
But it gets laggy when lot of elements are in conjuction. I'll post a jsfiddle soon. And speed is 400ms...which is pretty normal